# jQuery extend overwrites object and creates duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays where i want to extend array2 from array1 to get the 
"values".

But extend is overwriting another object too and thus creating a duplicate.

[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uF6dEuGZ2Y8ADakjdKjs)

```js
  var array1 = [{
attributeId: 2,
attributeName: "ToolOutput",
values: [
  "tool output value"
]
  }, {
attributeId: 4,
attributeName: "AggregationLevel",
values: [
  "aggregation level value"
]
  }];

  var array2 = [{
attributeId: 1,
attributeName: "DataToolsUsage",
values: []
  }, {
attributeId: 2,
attributeName: "ToolOutput",
values: []
  }, {
attributeId: 3,
attributeName: "ConnectedTo",
values: []
  }, {
attributeId: 4,
attributeName: "AggregationLevel",
values: []
  }];

  var newArray = $.extend({},array2, array1);

var printed = "result[0] is : <br> " + JSON.stringify(newArray[0]);
printed = printed + "<br><br> result[1] is : <br> " + JSON.stringify(newArray[1])
printed = printed + "<br><br> result[2] is : <br> " + JSON.stringify(newArray[2])
printed = printed + "<br><br> result[3] is : <br> " + JSON.stringify(newArray[3])
  
document.write(printed);
```

You can see in result two "AggregationLevel" objects. and also removal of "DataToolsUsage"

Any idea?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/uF6dEuGZ2Y8ADakjdKjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to call extend like this `$.extend({}, array1, array2)`. The first empty object is the target object where you want to store the result of extending array1 and array2. If you don't provide a target argument, then array1 is considered to be the target object and hence the values are overwritten. Refer https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ for more details on extend.

Comment: Same result , you can check the plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/uF6dEuGZ2Y8ADakjdKjs

Answer (score 0):

`$.extend` doesn't suit for a such task. You have two arrays of some objects, which has some custom identifier field. So if you want to merge your arrays, you should iterate all its items and populate result array manually. It can be done a littler bit easier with a library like `underscore`, but it is not necessary at all.